# Css animation doesn't work with transform

Tags: html, css, animation

For some reason in Chrome the animation I have created will move to the left first, then move to the desired position.

It should only be moving to the right and top.

**Css**

```
.intro .cogFade .cog {
    position: absolute;
}

.cog.large {
     animation-name: cog-large;
 }

@-webkit-keyframes cog-large {
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -40%) scale(1, 1);
  } 
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="intro">
        <div class="cogFade">
            <div class="cogElements" style="margin-top: 194px;">
                 <div class="circle zoomout" style="margin-top: 194px;"></div>
                 <div style="font-size: 5rem;" class="cog large">
                     <i class="icon-cog spinning"></i>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 15rem; display: none;" class="b breathing">
              <i class="icon-dotb"></i>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Please see the animation in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hutber/fejpm491/1/

Comment: Any chance you could slim that demo down to just the relevant code....there's a **lot** going on there. Offhand, I'd guess you have transforms overriding one another.

Comment: With over 1,100 lines of CSS, I doubt anyone is going to sift through it to try to find your problem. Try to narrow that down to just what part of the animation isn't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put your posted code into a JSFiddle, as the one linked by you was way too big to work with.

First off, the `-webkit-` prefix isn't needed anymore for animations in Chrome.

Your problem is that there are no proper initial values for `position`, `left` and `top`, leading to an in fact no completely defined animation. As you may have noticed, browsers behave differently in that case, as the animation looked different in Chrome and Firefox.

Just make sure that `position: absolute` is always true independently of the animation, then set proper start and end values for `left` and `top`.

[**Example based on your code**](http://jsfiddle.net/xyaruv9k/2/)

Comment: Thanks Cedric :) You are super helpful and worthy of my upvote :)